# Android color code for action bar in holo light theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am making an app using Holo dark theme, though I want the action bar to be the same grey like color in Holo light/ default theme. What is the color code that i can use for that?
Thanks

Comment: I believe that combination does not exist, you'd have to create a theme specifically for that. Even though i fail to see why you want that (I envision that as a very ugly user interface) you can do it with http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All colors are stored here :

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml

The color you looking for is :  `#fff3f3f3`

Answer (score 0):

`#ddd`

I couldn't figure out how to reference the one already defined, so I just made my own.

`<color name="action_bar_background">#ddd</color>`